# Customise Default WinMain.cpp on Project Creation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

When I create a new Win32 Project in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and it creates the default WinMain.cpp file with the default WinMain function...

**Is it possible to load a different WinMain.cpp file, ie, my own WinMain.cpp file/template?**

Hope that makes sense. To be more specific, I want to have different default code in WinMain.cpp whenever I create a new Win32 Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it years ago with VC6 - it is known as **Custom Project Wizard**.

In **New Project -> General** select `Custom Wizard` to start off.

Using custom wizard, you can create a new wizard type to create project. You'd setup the wizard as per your needs, code the logic and things like that. Once done, and registered your wizard will come as another type.

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bhceedxx.aspx